# PhpStorm - Filename color extremely bad, how to change it?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.3

I changed my theme to Darcula and I noticed that the file names on the left are not rendering. Maybe the color is just the same as the background. Some file names are visible, I can see the name if I select a file.

[image]

I was not able to find the option which is responsible for this color settings.

Comment: Actually a restart of the IDE should fix that problem. If not, try "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart" and select "Invalidate and Restart" in the window that will be displayed.

Comment: **1)** Ensure that you use Darcula editor scheme as well; If you are -- switch to Default, OK to exit Settings screen; enter the Settings screen again and switch to Darcula again. **2)** If still nothing -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | File Status` -- check them there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it under `settings`->`Editor`->`Colors & Fonts` -> `File status`

I had to change `Up to date` to another color.